# Is there a way to obtain referenced issues of a sheet through Autodesk Construction Cloud API?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I want to get sheet referenced issues in Autodesk Construction Cloud (ACC). From my understanding, references are obtained using the Relationships API. (eg. getting issues referenced photos)

I tried using this [API](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/relationship-service-v2-search-relationships-GET/), but the response only include entities of type "markup" and "markupsheethistory", nothing related to sheets (Note: issue with id "ed459d9e-1a1d-4296-809a-35ad0977be7d" is a reference in a sheet). The [GET Sheets API](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/sheets-sheets-GET/) also does not return anything related to references.

```
{
    "relationships": [
        {
            "permission": null,
            "id": "f888c048-a155-5e56-abd0-cee4bc01f4a4",
            "createdOn": "2023-03-13T03:45:23.259626+00:00",
            "isReadOnly": false,
            "isService": true,
            "isDeleted": false,
            "entities": [
                {
                    "createdOn": "2023-03-13T03:45:23.253702+00:00",
                    "domain": "autodesk-construction-markup",
                    "type": "markupsheethistory",
                    "id": "dcdc79df-e6c1-4f33-8e20-1a397a5732ca"
                },
                {
                    "createdOn": "2023-03-13T03:45:23.253702+00:00",
                    "domain": "autodesk-bim360-issue",
                    "type": "issue",
                    "id": "ed459d9e-1a1d-4296-809a-35ad0977be7d"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "permission": null,
            "id": "a58b0b20-71f0-46f4-ba4c-136f931e53ea",
            "createdOn": "2023-03-13T03:45:23.428655+00:00",
            "isReadOnly": false,
            "isService": true,
            "isDeleted": false,
            "entities": [
                {
                    "createdOn": "2023-03-13T03:45:23.253702+00:00",
                    "domain": "autodesk-bim360-issue",
                    "type": "issue",
                    "id": "ed459d9e-1a1d-4296-809a-35ad0977be7d"
                },
                {
                    "createdOn": "2023-03-13T03:45:23.423232+00:00",
                    "domain": "autodesk-construction-markup",
                    "type": "markup",
                    "id": "98c2c899-c7f8-4315-910a-175e3d4fec26"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Am I using the right API? Or how should I make use of the entities of type "markup" and "markupsheethistory"?

Comment: Relationship API only manages the Relationships of the entities. It is not always a pair with the first class entities (like Issue, RFI...) For some complex workflow, it may bind an advanced entity which contains information of the first class entities.  e.g.  to get corresponding issue, call issue API. While as you have known, we have not exposed Markup API.  I'd believe the Sheet's id can be found by markupsheethistory  if using Markup API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, no Markup API yet, but I found you may take advantage of Data Connector API. This API is to dump data of single project or all projects and admin data in a batch job. It now supports to export Markup information.

After it is done, the package contains a lot of csv files. you can start to use Sheet id to find corresponding markup id in markups_placement.csv. In this csv, sheet id is called surface_id. After getting markup id, you can find the associated issue id by Relationship API.

Actually, Data Connector API can also dump Issue, Sheet data and even Relationship data. So if you want to save some codes, you could analyze related csv together.

about Data Connector API, please check these blogs:

https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/bim-360-data-connector-api-available-public-beta

https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/accbim-360-insight-data-connector-api-project-level-access

[image]